# NodeJS Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, push, puppeteer

I have a function scraping some data on a page, and storing them in a variable "result". There are several pages, thus the function is included in a "for" loop.

```
const PageScraping = async(page, query) =>{
await page.goto(query, { waitUntil: "networkidle2" });

const result = await page.evaluate(() =>{
        return(
            [...document.querySelectorAll('.card--result__body')].map((o) => ({
                type:
                    o.querySelector('.card__title-link') &&
                    o.querySelector('.card__title-link').innerText,
                price:
                    o.querySelector('.card--result__price > span > .sr-only') &&
                    parseInt(o.querySelector('.card--result__price > span > .sr-only').innerText.replace('€','')),
                rooms:
                    o.querySelector('.card__informations.card--result__informations > .card__information.card--result__information.card__information--property > .abbreviation > .sr-only') &&
                    parseInt(o.querySelector('.card__informations.card--result__informations > .card__information.card--result__information.card__information--property > .abbreviation > .sr-only').innerText.replace(' chambres','')),
                surface:
                    o.querySelector('.card__information.card--result__information.card__information--property') &&
                    parseInt(o.querySelector('.card__information.card--result__information.card__information--property').innerText.split(' ')[4]),
                postcode:
                    o.querySelector('.card__information.card--results__information--locality.card__information--locality') &&
                    o.querySelector('.card__information.card--results__information--locality.card__information--locality').innerText.split(' ')[0],
                url:
                    o.querySelector('.card__title.card--result__title > a') &&
                    o.querySelector('.card__title.card--result__title > a').href,
            }))
            );
        });
return result;
```

}

After, I need to store result, in another variable containing all the data (loop). There I'm using "push", but I got an error :

> Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

```
    let all_results;
    try{
       let query = 'myurl'
       await page.goto(query, { waitUntil: "networkidle2" });
       let max_pages = parseInt(await page.$eval('.pagination > li:nth-last-child(2) > a > .button__label', o => o.innerText));
       for(let i = 1; i < max_pages+1; i++){
           console.log('page ',i,' of ',max_pages);
           try{
               const result = await PageScraping(page, query);
               query = `urlpage${i+1}`;
               all_results.push(result);
               console.log(all_results);

            } catch(e){
               console.log('ERROR: could not reach landing page',e.message);
           }
       }

   } catch(error) {
       console.log('ERROR: could not reach landing page',error.message);

   } finally {
       try{
           await browser.close();
        }catch(browser_error){
            console.log('ERROR cant close browser??', browser_error.message)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's `all_results`? I don't see it defined anywhere.

Comment: Can you show us where you defined the `all_results` variable? It tries to read it from there as methods are just properties with function type

Comment: define all_results as an array, push method is for array

Comment: I just edited the question including all_results definition

Comment: you have *declared* `all_results`, but don't appear to ever assign a value to it - so it will of course be `undefined`, which is what the error is telling you. If you expect it to hold an array, you have to assign the appropriate array value at some point.

Comment: Now, it works with the let all_results = []; thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code is working now. As suggested, I declared "all_results" as an array.

```
    let all_results = [];
    try{
       let query = 'myurl'
       await page.goto(query, { waitUntil: "networkidle2" });
       let max_pages = parseInt(await page.$eval('.pagination > li:nth-last-child(2) > a > .button__label', o => o.innerText));
       for(let i = 1; i < max_pages+1; i++){
           console.log('page ',i,' of ',max_pages);
           try{
               const result = await PageScraping(page, query);
               query = `urlpage${i+1}`;
               all_results.push(result);
               console.log(all_results);

            } catch(e){
               console.log('ERROR: could not reach landing page',e.message);
           }
       }

   } catch(error) {
       console.log('ERROR: could not reach landing page',error.message);

   } finally {
       try{
           await browser.close();
        }catch(browser_error){
            console.log('ERROR cant close browser??', browser_error.message)
        }
    }
}
```